# PDO connect to db with classes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im making a PDO system and got a problem/question. I gonna make multiple classes for my codes, for users, products etc. And I was wondering about the connection. I have this in one of my classes:

```
class Database
{
    private $_db;

    function __construct($db)
    {    
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
}
```

`$db` comes from a config file, where I also load all the classes in. The question is now:

Do I have to create the same function in all the classes or can i just have my "database" class that work for all my classes?

Comment: I'd say this is more a basic concept you want to learn more about. It's called [Object Inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) and what you're looking for is perhaps an [abstract base class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php). - And the answer to your question is: No, you don't have to create the same function in all the classes. Yes, you can have your database class work "for" all your database classes (and those classes are then database classes, always, see [single inheritance in PHP](http://phppot.com/php/php-inheritance/)).

Comment: @hakre show him how to do it

Comment: So in the other classes i need to put extends Database, and what more do i need?

Comment: @hakre Sounds like Laravel's `Eloquent`

Comment: @JensJørgen: There is a whole world of what you could do more, but technically the concept is already to extend from the **Database** class - as you wrote it! A complete bunch of database related examples can be found in Chapter 10 of *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*. It's not PHP code but most of the concepts you can map onto PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to ([and shouldn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) create the same function over and over again for every class. That makes it very hard to maintain your application.

Try one of the following methods:

### 1. Dependency Injection

You can use dependency injection to do this. This is very situational and probably not what you're looking for, but I thought I'd put it here anyway.

Assume the following:

```
class Database
{
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}

class User
{
    /**
     * @var Database
     */
    private $db;

    // Here we inject a Database object (as hinted by Database $db) into the current instance
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db
    }
}

try
{
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
    $db = new Database($pdo);
}

catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    // Could not connect to database or some other error message
}



// Inject $db in the user class
$user = new User($db);
```

### 2. Singleton

You can make your Database class a singleton and then call it statically. This might be more what you need.

```
class Database
{
    /**
     * @var Database
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $db;

    protected function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    // You'd call this in your config
    public static function initialize(PDO $db)
    {
        if(self::$instance == null)
        {
            // Create a new instance of this class
            self::$instance = new self($db);
        }
    }

    // Get the instance
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }

    // Do something
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // Do something
        echo "Foo";
    }
}

class User
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // This would print "Foo"
        Database::instance()->doSomething();
    }
}

try
{
    $db = new PDO(...);
}

catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    // Could not connect to database or some other error message
}

Database::initialize($db);

$user = new User();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need any singleton for that. You can just use the global variable. That said, better use dependency injection. I wonder that singleton is still suggested at the end of 2014. All you want is a super static: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhPyr.png (<- Christmas Edition)

Comment: I get following error in my database class: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Database::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, none given.` Also do i need to add `$user = new User($db);` in the user class or can i add it on a config file?

Comment: Which method do you use?

Comment: So if i copy everything that you wrote, it should work right?

Comment: @JensJørgen Pretty much, but it's best you write it for your needs.